# Position of `@` label in Kotlin when denoting receiver with `this`

Tags: kotlin, this, grammar

I am a newbie in Kotlin. I am curious about the difference of labeled `this` in Kotlin with prefix `@` or postfix `@`.

I have just seen a code which writes `SignInActivity@this`, which seems to work exactly same as `this@SignInActivity`.

Are these two exactly the same thing? If not, what is the difference between the two?

I was trying to do some research on `*@this` form, but I couldn't find any reference on it. All I could find was [this official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) which demonstrates `this@*`. It will be nice if anybody could share me with the correct reference I should go to.

Comment: This seems valid, interestingly

Comment: @1blustone it really does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SignInActivity@ this` is just another expression for `this`, with the functionality of defining an unnecessary label called `SignInActivity`(which has nothing to do with actual class name) for `this`.

According to [Kotlin grammar documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#labelReference):

```
labelReference (used by atomicExpression, jump)
   : "@" ++ LabelName
   ;
labelDefinition (used by prefixUnaryOperation, annotatedLambda)
  : LabelName ++ "@"
  ;
```

`hello@` is just a label with the name "hello" (for [Returns and Jumps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#returns-and-jumps)) ,

whereas `@hello` is a reference for the labeled loop or block.

These expressions combined can be used as below:

```
loop@ for (i in 1..100) {
    for (j in 1..100) {
        if (...) break@loop //jump to loop@
   }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot. So it was only a superstition. lol.

Answer (score 5):

SignInActivity@this means SignInActivity.this (Java)
this@SignInActivity means - using the  SignInActivity context instead a local context (usually is in closures).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. After some testing, I'm kind of convinced that what you are saying is actually correct. But could you provide me with some reference or spec to elaborate? Because when I see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols which demonstrates the usage of `@`, I don't find any proof that `@` can used as a postfix as in `SignInActivity@ this`.

Comment: The link you provided actually lists that `@` can [reference a 'this' expression from an outer scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified).

Comment: @zsmb13 Yes, but notice that it's in a form of `this@label`, not `label@this`

Comment: Oh, right, my bad, I just skimmed the original post. It's fascinating that this works too.